# Is it good practice to return an error to the caller instead of throwing the error right away in C++

Tags: c++

Is it considered good practice to return an error to the caller function like in Go, or should my program throw an error instead when it encounters it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are different common practices w.r.t. error handling in C++ - as it is a multi-paradigmatic language. For example:

- Return status/error codes rather than results.
- Return results only, throw exceptions on error.
- Return value-or-error objects, such as [std::expected](https://isocpp.org/blog/2018/01/introduction-to-proposed-stdexpected).

Each of these has pros and cons. The most important thing is to **be consistent** in your program, and to *coordinate with whoever calls your functions** - so that you meet their needs.

For a detailed presentation of current options and a future potential alternative, see this talk by Brand & Nash at the annual C++ conference CppCon:

[CppCon 2018: "What Could Possibly Go Wrong?: A Tale of Expectations and Exceptions"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GC4cp4U2f2E)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your viewpoint. Some people swear by throwing exceptions, others will point out some of the following:

C++ has been designed to support exception-free operation with zero overhead, with the consequence that the throwing code paths are more involved. **Exceptions are exceptionally slow when thrown**. So, at the very least, you should avoid throwing exceptions within the performance critical code paths.

Another argument against exceptions is, that **correct error handling is as much of a code feature as anything else**, and that it helps to have the error code paths explicit.

A third argument against exceptions is, that C++ has been designed to allow overloading of any operators, allowing such straightforward statements like `a = b;` to throw. As such, **code written to use exceptions must be written in a special exception safe way** (construct in local variables and `swap()` to commit changes) if exceptions are allowed in a program.

As a corollary, **code written to use exceptions simply does not mix well with code that avoids exceptions**. The later will not be written in an exception safe style, and consequently blow up in your face when an exception skips parts of its execution.

---

Sorry, I don't know any good arguments *for* using exceptions. All the arguments I've seen ("it makes the code cleaner" and such) don't really seem to cut it, imho. Please refer to some exception enthusiasts for arguments for using exceptions.

---

**Bottom line:**
There are many projects out there that fully embrace exceptions, and there are other projects that ban them from their code. And because the codes of these two camps don't mix well, you will need to stick to how the project that you are working does it.

Comment: Using exceptions allows you to write code which - mostly - assumes there are no errors. It lets you focus on the computational tasks at hand, rather than "ontological noise"; and handle that "noise" separately (as a developer, not as the CPU running the code).

Comment: @einpoklum Yeah, I know that argument. I just fail to find it convincing. Especially in C++ where you need to replace writing error handling code with writing exception safe code - and still have to deal with the errors. But, of course, YMMV, and I guess we have to agree to disagree :-)